# Arranging Drivers and Passengers from IB Math AA HL

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> A group of $12$ people want to go a concert.  They can travel in a small car that takes on driver and one passenger and two cars each taking one driver and four passengers.  If there are five drivers in the group, in how many ways can they travel?

The solution in the textbook is $6300$ but I have no idea how they got to that answer.

So far, here is what I've tried: $nPr(5,3) \cdot nCr(9,1) \cdot nCr(8,4) \cdot nCr(4,4) = 37800$

I'm not sure whether my work is correct or not, but here's my chain of logic:

- There are $5$ drivers going into $3$ cars, and the order that we pick them does matter because the drivers are in different cars. That's where $nPr(5,3)$ comes from.
- There are $9$ people left total. In the first car, we are choosing $1$ person out of the $9$. Then, in the second car, we are choosing $4$ people out of the $8$ people left. Then, in the third car, we are choosing $4$ people out of the $4$ people left.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting a link since links may get broken.

Answer (score 2):

The drivers can be placed in $5\cdot4\cdot3 = 60$ ways

There are spaces for $1, 4,4$ people in the three cars. Since no seating arrangement has been specified, they can be placed in $\binom9 1 \binom 84 \binom 4 4 = 630$ ways

Multiply to get $60\cdot630 = 37800$

Your answer seems correct to me

Comment: The book answer is lower by a factor of 6, I can't see why !

Comment: The book seems to have used $\binom 5 3$ for placing the drivers, which is incorrect.